# WSDL and field validation

Tags: java, web-services

I am working on web services soap and rest.
Testing my web service,i passed a duplicate field ProductId as in the example below,and pass without any problem.

I am asking is it a normal behavior or it is a bug?

Any help,is very appreciate.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:v1="http://nameSpace/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <getProductService>
        <arg0>
            <ProductDate>2016-04-01</ProductDate>
            <ProductId>prod1</ProductId>
            ##<ProductId>prod1</ProductId>##
        </arg0>
  </getProductService>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: My comment is not about question, but anyway just in case: You little bit misunderstood these two technologies: soap and rest. They are not the same and not used together. You created JAX-WS web-service, which uses SOAP protocol

Comment: Thanks i.merkurev for your comment,where did you see that i am using rest and soap together?

Comment: "I am working on web services soap and rest" - i thought that you try to use soap and rest together :)

Comment: It depends on the schema used or defined in the WSDL and whether elements are defined with `minOccurs` and/or `maxOccurs`. As visible in section 2.2.1 of the [XSD schema reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#POSchema) different values lead to different outcomes. A min and max value of 1 specify that the element must occur only once while setting a higher max boundary allows for multiple definitions of the same element. By default, however, if neither of these properties are present, both, min- and maxOccurs have a default value of 1 stating that the element has to appear only once.

Comment: @RomanVottner, thanks for your answer,it becomes a little clear now. Please,where i can set minOccurs and maxOccurs?

Comment: Are you the maintainer of the WSDL/XSD? If not I'm afraid you can't modify it unless you download the definition manually and alter the file before converting the schema to stub-code. If you are the maintainer (or want to alter the WSDL/XSD locally) you might want to follow [a tutorial such as this](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_complex_indicators.asp)

Comment: Thanks @RomanVottner.the WSDL it generated,and i don't have an xsd file.i am using cxf apache with version 3.1.8